# How to secure a file from anonymous and authenticated user in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to build a media library system but don't know how to go about securing my files from anybody body who want to hack my system. I don't want any user to use one particular link to access my files, I want only user who can buy the media to have access to a particular file. if one "friend" access it, and then give the file URL to unauthorized person the friend should not be able to access it.

for example, if I have the following link, how do I go about make another person not to have access to it.

```
https://a4.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/296040_2530953916384_1329592446_32898884_1499197273_n.jpg
```

I will like know how I can go about implementing this in Asp.Net MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Following [LINK] (http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/id-291916.html) to do that.  Im Sured it Helps.